# Is it poor form to use .ToString() or another method inside of Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using .ToString() inside of my view to output to currency format. Should I convert the values to a string prior to rendering the view? Also, why does the second h3 tag below not create a currency string like the first does?

EX:

```
<h3>Healthcare Cost Per Paycheck: @Model.TotalCostPerPaycheck.ToString("C")</h3>

<h3>Net Pay for @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName: @(Model.Salary - Model.TotalCostPerYear).ToString("C") </h3>
```

Output:

Healthcare Cost Per Paycheck: $71.16

Net Pay for Albert Wilson: 50150.ToString("C")

Comment: Try another pair of parenthesis `@((Model.Salary - Model.TotalCostPerYear).ToString("C"))`

Comment: As for the first part of your question, it's probably too opinion-based for stackoverflow, but I don't see anything wrong with the way you're doing it. I'm not really a front-end guy, but things like formatting objects to display to the user should definitely be handled in the UI layer.

Comment: I'd say doing very trivial object manipulation / formatting like here is fine in the view.  That way your view model can appear more reasonable, and potentially reusable

Comment: Using `ToString()` inside a razor view can lead to an exception if the original string is empty, therefore always check for `null` or `empty` using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method and then access your property and use `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try-

```
<h3>
   Healthcare Cost Per Paycheck: @(Model.TotalCostPerPaycheck.ToString("C"))
</h3>

<h3>
    Net Pay for @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName: @((Model.Salary - Model.TotalCostPerYear).ToString("C")) 
</h3>
```

For Quick Reference about Razor Syntax you can see [this](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) article.

Comment: extra parentheses did it. Thanks, everyone. I agree about putting NetPay in my model as well.

Answer (score 1):

No that isn't a poor form. It's a bit opinion based if you ask me though. What i do think you should do is make your view code also readable for others that will join you on the project.

For instance, i would advice you to create a new property called `NetPay` or something like that where you'll calculate the values in the backend (or where your business logic is defined) and use it in your view instead of creating you own calculations in the view.

You'll able to just call the property and everyone would understand what the meaning of that part is in your view. Also whenever your logic has to be changed, you'll only need to change the part in the backend once instead of, when you use this logic accross multiple views, multiple times. And the beautify is it all is, you can create a fallback logic in case your value (not sure if that's possible because i can't see your model) is null.

Hope that makes sense and good luck!